# Filter in Nested Data Frame

Tags: json, r, filter, nested, dplyr

I am playing around with the Yelp data set and want to filter the business set according to the category.

I imported the JSON file into R with

```
yelp_business = stream_in(file("yelp_academic_dataset_business.json"))
```

which results then in the following data frame:

```
  'data.frame': 77445 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ business_id  : chr  "5UmKMjUEUNdYWqANhGckJw" "UsFtqoBl7naz8AVUBZMjQQ" "3eu6MEFlq2Dg7bQh8QbdOg" "cE27W9VPgO88Qxe4ol6y_g" ...
 $ full_address : chr  "4734 Lebanon Church Rd\nDravosburg, PA 15034" "202 McClure St\nDravosburg, PA 15034" "1 Ravine St\nDravosburg, PA 15034" "1530 Hamilton Rd\nBethel Park, PA 15234" ...
 $ hours        :'data.frame':  77445 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ Friday   :'data.frame':   77445 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ close: chr  "21:00" NA NA NA ...
  .. ..$ open : chr  "11:00" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Tuesday  :'data.frame':   77445 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ close: chr  "21:00" NA NA NA ...
  .. ..$ open : chr  "11:00" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Thursday :'data.frame':   77445 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ close: chr  "21:00" NA NA NA ...
  .. ..$ open : chr  "11:00" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Wednesday:'data.frame':   77445 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ close: chr  "21:00" NA NA NA ...
  .. ..$ open : chr  "11:00" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Monday   :'data.frame':   77445 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ close: chr  "21:00" NA NA NA ...
  .. ..$ open : chr  "11:00" NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Sunday   :'data.frame':   77445 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ close: chr  NA NA NA NA ...
  .. ..$ open : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ Saturday :'data.frame':   77445 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ close: chr  NA NA NA NA ...
  .. ..$ open : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ open         : logi  TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE TRUE ...
 $ categories   :List of 77445
  ..$ : chr  "Fast Food" "Restaurants"
  ..$ : chr "Nightlife"
  ..$ : chr  "Auto Repair" "Automotive"
  ..$ : chr  "Active Life" "Mini Golf" "Golf"
  ..$ : chr  "Shopping" "Home Services" "Internet Service Providers" "Mobile Phones" ...
  ..$ : chr  "Bars" "American (New)" "Nightlife" "Lounges" ...
  ..$ : chr  "Active Life" "Trainers" "Fitness & Instruction"
  ..$ : chr  "Bars" "American (Traditional)" "Nightlife" "Restaurants"
  ..$ : chr  "Auto Repair" "Automotive" "Tires"
  ..$ : chr  "Active Life" "Mini Golf"
  ..$ : chr  "Home Services" "Contractors"
  ..$ : chr  "Veterinarians" "Pets"
  ..$ : chr  "Libraries" "Public Services & Government"
  ..$ : chr  "Automotive" "Auto Parts & Supplies"
```

I now want to filter all rows according to the business category and want to include all categories that have food in the category list.

However, if I just try it that way:

```
input ="food"
engage = filter(yelp_business, grepl(input, categories))
```

I receive the following error code:

```
Error: data_frames can only contain 1d atomic vectors and lists
```

I first suspected the nested structure to be a reason for that. However using tidyjson does not help either as category is a list and not a dataframe within the main dataframe.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this? I just need a list of all food restaurant's business ids to then filter the review json file from Yelp to extract the written reviews.

Any help with this is really appreciated! Thanks a lot!

Comment: try `yelp_business$categories <- unlist(yelp_business$categories)`

Comment: Thanks Pierre, I tried this also, but the problem is that each row in categories has a different number of category tags. Unlisting results in 227451 new rows instead of the necessary 77445 rows so that I get the following error message:
`Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "categories", value = c("Fast Food",  : 
  replacement has 227451 rows, data has 77445`

Comment: That isn't the problem. See `grepl("a", list(c("a", "b"), "c"))`. The issue is the nested data frames above.

Comment: Can you add `dput(yelp_business[1:2, 1:5])`?

Answer (score 0):

`tidyjson` does not [yet](https://github.com/jeremystan/tidyjson/issues/20) support ndjson, and I am not quite sure how to nicely work with `stream_in()`.

However, it is possible to read the file directly and process naturally with `tidyjson`.  I am using the development version from `devtools::install_github('jeremystan/tidyjson')`.

`document.id` gives a nice identification of objects, so I find the `document.id`s that have "food" in one of the "categories."  From that point, we filter and do whatever additional data analysis is desired.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyjson)

j <- readLines("yelp_academic_dataset_business.json")

raw <- j %>% as.tbl_json()

## pull out the categories for filtering
prep <- raw %>% enter_object("categories") %>% 
  gather_array() %>% append_values_string()

## filter to 'food' categories (use document.id to identify json objects)
keepids <- prep[str_detect(str_to_lower(prep$string), "food"), ]$document.id %>% 
  unique()

## filter and do any further data analysis you want to do
raw %>% filter(document.id %in% keepids) %>% 
 spread_values(
  name = json_chr(name), 
  city = json_chr(city),
  state = json_chr(state), 
  stars = json_chr(stars))
#> # A tbl_json: 21 x 5 tibble with a "JSON" attribute
#>         `attr(., "JSON")` document.id                      name       city
#>                     <chr>       <int>                     <chr>      <chr>
#>  1 "{\"business_id\":..."           2             Cut and Taste  Las Vegas
#>  2 "{\"business_id\":..."           8                 Taco Bell Scottsdale
#>  3 "{\"business_id\":..."          10           Sehne Backwaren  Stuttgart
#>  4 "{\"business_id\":..."          20   Graceful Cake Creations       Mesa
#>  5 "{\"business_id\":..."          26    Chipotle Mexican Grill    Toronto
#>  6 "{\"business_id\":..."          30  Carrabba's Italian Grill   Glendale
#>  7 "{\"business_id\":..."          32             I Deal Coffee    Toronto
#>  8 "{\"business_id\":..."          34 Lo-Lo's Chicken & Waffles    Phoenix
#>  9 "{\"business_id\":..."          38              Kabob Palace  Las Vegas
#> 10 "{\"business_id\":..."          43              Tea Shop 168    Markham
#> # ... with 11 more rows, and 2 more variables: state <chr>, stars <chr>
```

NOTE - I only processed the first 100 records of the `yelp_academic_dataset_business.json` file.